# Is service-worker with CacheAPI or IndexedDB viable for downloading large datasets

Tags: service-worker

I have a following situation: I am developing a small web application with the following properties:

- must be available offline (it is intended for outdoor use in areas with poor cell reception)
- when online, each user "produces" his/her own offline content which is placed inside a publicly available folder for each user on the server. This content (sets of images, up to 40Mb per user, to be concrete) is necessary for the app to have any usefulness

First point is fine, service workers are just the thing i need as they will download and cache my application logic, but i am struggling to figure out, if i should or even can use service workers for the last requirement. As i understand, service workers have the following property: the structure of a service worker (what is included) is determined at application build step and cannot be changed or modified at runtime, and even if it was, i could not generate different service-workers for different users, correct?

Is there another approach for this?

Comment: not able to understand the problem here. why you want create two service worker for same application. Can you please elaborate

Comment: Yes, of course you can. But the way i see it (using vue cli 3 pwa plugin) is, that service worker script file is something that is created during the webpack build process, so you can't change it at runtime, and certainly not make a prticular version of it for every single user. That said, i'm just now reading through an IndexedDB tutorial, which is probably the way to go here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Cache Storage API to cache additional content for users, beyond your web app's HTML/JS/CSS. The Cache Storage API is exposed to both client web pages and inside of a service worker as `caches` on the global object.

You can, for instance, make the following call within your web app's code:

```
async function cacheAdditionalUrls(urls) {
  const cache = await caches.open('my-custom-cache');
  await cache.addAll(url);
  // At this point, 'my-custom-cache' will contain all of the urls.
  // You can read from this cache from the service worker.
}
```

And in your service worker, you can read from `'my-custom-cache'` to fulfill matching requests. You mention that you're using `vue-cli`'s PWA plugin, which is built on top of [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/). To use that cached data in Workbox, you can implement a [`runtimeCaching` rule](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-build#generateSW-runtimeCaching) in the [Workbox configuration](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-pwa#configuration), like so:

```
pwa: {
  workboxOptions: {
    // Add in other options as needed.
    runtimeCaching: [{
      urlPattern: new RegExp('path/prefix/for/images'),
      handler: 'cacheFirst',
      options: {
        cacheName: 'my-custom-cache'
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Studying the docs a little further, see it is recommended to use Cache API for application files (html, js, css) and IndexedDB for other data, so i think i ll stick with that. I found a good example for using IndexedDB to do just that: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/storing-images-and-files-in-indexeddb/ (old link, but the concept is still relevant, and IndexedDB 2.0 is now widely supported)